# Put dir into RAM like log2ram to save IOPs

Tags: nginx

I have one quite IOPs-limited VM with small RAM and quite powerful CPU. So to say, I have only 300 IOPs and 500 Mb of RAM, and the VM is for serving static html files only with nginx.

The problem is, even when I rsync new filetree into docroot, I spend like 30 minutes since there are a lot of files and disk is limited.

So, I suspect I can put the docroot into RAM, but prefer to have it synced to disk automatically. One such a script os log2ram, but maybe there is a mature utility/script to do the same for any dir?

Please advice! I understand good idea is to change the storage policy, but this is not possible so far, and I do suspect it is possible to have this VM serve files anyway!

Comment: Why not use a ramdisk rather than a solution specific for the webserver?  (With only the webfiles served from that disk)

Comment: What underlying OS, and how much data to sync?  Also, are you using LVM?

Comment: @Hennes ramdisk or tmpfs is good, I just hate to do manual sync disk to ramdisk, and looking for such a script

Comment: @davidgo Ubuntu 18.04 is the OS

Comment: I wonder if this would do you - https://blog.jmdawson.co.uk/persistent-ramdisk-on-debain-ubuntu/ - i've not tried it, but it is a script that takes a ramdisk and persists it to disk in the background.